# [Date].[Calendar Year].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN not picking up children

Tags: ssas, mdx

If I run the following the two custom measures return the same results. Why doesn't `[Measures].[AvgOfChildren]` return the average for the level below `[Calendar Year]` ?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Yearly Reseller Sales Amount] AS
    AVG(
        {[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS},
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
MEMBER [Measures].[AvgOfChildren] AS
    AVG(
        {[Date].[Calendar Year].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN}, //[Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Avg Yearly Reseller Sales Amount],
    [Measures].[AvgOfChildren]} ON 0,
    {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].MEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement does not contain any setting for the `[Date].[Calendar Year]` hierarchy, neither in a `WHERE` condition, nor in the rows. And this means that the `CurrentMember` has the default value, which is the ``All member, named `All Periods` in this case.

You can verify this by adding another calculated member

```
Measures.CurrentYear as [Date].[Calendar Year].CURRENTMEMBER.NAME
```

and adding that to your columns.

Comment: @FrankPI - I suspect this is an easy one for yourself? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931364/using-generate-to-concatenate-rank-and-member-name

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not using the correct hierarchy to get the answer you are expecting.

You asked for [date].[calendar year].currentmember.children in your AvgOfChildren calculation, but I think you meant to use [date].**[calendar]**.[calendar year].currentmember.children.

The [date].[calendar year] hierarchy is the one created for the calendar year attribute. The [date].[calendar] hierarchy is the user defined hierarchy with many levels that probably looks something like calendar year -> calendar quarter -> month -> date. When you ask for the children of the calendar year on this hierarchy you should expect the answer to be different because it is using quarter (or whatever you have as the level under calendar year).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a [Date].[Calendar Year].CurrentMember defined. There's no mention to the [Date] dimension in the Rows.

Try this instead:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Avg Yearly Reseller Sales Amount] AS
    AVG(
        {[Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS},
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
MEMBER [Measures].[AvgOfChildren] AS
    AVG(
        {[Date].[Calendar Year].CURRENTMEMBER.CHILDREN}, //[Date].[Calendar].[Month].MEMBERS
        [Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])
SELECT
    {[Measures].[Avg Yearly Reseller Sales Amount],
    [Measures].[AvgOfChildren]} ON 0,
    {[Geography].[Geography].[Country].MEMBERS} * [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

The first column will give you the yearly average (same value for all years), the second will give you the average of the year's children.